# How to get Alt-nnnn keyboard shortcuts to work under Linux?

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, kde, arch-linux

A few weeks ago, I switched from Windows to Linux, and one thing I'm missing is <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>nnnn</kbd> keyboard shortcuts to insert an em dash and other things. Is there any way to get them working under Linux? I'm using Arch Linux and KDE, if that matters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Using numeric code points

In Tobu's answer, I believe the keystroke combination on US or UK keyboards would be called <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> as in "Ctrl-Shift-2702 is for the scissors character (✂)".

Personally I find it much easier to remember digraphs.

## Digraphs / Compose-Key / Multi-Key

### X11 Modmap

The X Window system (X11) provides for what is sometimes called a [compose key](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ComposeKey) which allows the entry of special characters by using digraphs.

> Keying the combination Shift+AltGr (in that order), releasing these
>   keys, then entering two other keys will produce a special character.
>   Many of these will be the reasonable result of overtyping the
>   character keys, eg.

```
Shift+AltGr  ~  a -->  ã  (ã in HTML)
Shift+AltGr  /  o -->  ø  (ø in HTML)
Shift+AltGr  o  c -->  ©  (© in HTML)
Shift+AltGr  c  o -->  ǒ  (Ŏ in HTML)
```

### How to

There is an [article](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/blog/mtk358-492316/how-to-enable-the-compose-key-in-x-2885/) at linuxquestions.org that describes how to set this up.

> first you need to choose which key you want to be the Compose key.
>   Then, open a terminal and enter the command `xev`.
>   A window called "Event Tester" will pop up. Make sure that
>   it's focused by clicking on it and leaving the mouse cursor in it.
>
> Now press and release the key that you want to become the Compose key.
>   Remember or write down the number after the word "keycode" in the
>   output
>
> Now open the file ".Xmodmap" (the name begins with a dot) in your home
>   directory (create it if it isn't there already) with a text editor and
>   type in the following line, replacing  with the number
>   you got in xev.
>
> `keycode <keycode number> = Multi_key` Now, open the file .xinitrc
>   (it's in your home directory, and it's a hidden file) in a text
>   editor. Insert this line in the beginning of the file:
>
> `xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap` And next time you log in the Compose key
>   should work! To start using the Compose key right now, enter the
>   command `xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap` in a terminal.

### Wikipedia

The howto article refers to a [wikepdia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compose_key#Compose_key_in_various_computer_systems) which says

> The compose key is known as "Multi_key"
>   in the X Window System, and must be interpreted by the client
>   program (typically Xlib), not the server. In XFree86 and X.Org Server,
>   many keyboard layouts have a variant that maps Multi_key to some key,
>   usually (on PC keyboards) to either of the Windows keys, or sometimes
>   ⇧ Shift+AltGr[1] or ⇧ Shift+Right-Ctrl. It can also be specified in
>   XkbOptions (for example, "compose:rwin"). Multi_key can also be
>   assigned with the xmodmap(1) utility.

Comment: I'm using KDE, but I found [this](http://userbase.kde.org/ComposeKey) based on your answer (*compose key in Ubuntu* link), and also [this](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:3uiCn9M_FssJ:ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-428265.html+Compose+key+em+dash&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&client=firefox-a&source=www.google.com), which tells how to get em dash with the compose key. Thank you!

Comment: The compose key is an X11 feature, not distro-specific.

Comment: @grawity: Updated answer to make this clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Gtk/Gnome has Ctrl-Shift-U, followed by the digits of the unicode character, then enter. Additionally “—” may be available in the standard keyboard layout for your language, or an alternative one. Mine is at AltGr-Shift-4 for example; `gnome-keyboard-properties` can display the layout so you can look for keys.

Comment: Only one problem with that... I'm using KDE, not Gnome.